# what does "at" sign @ stand for in R?

Tags: r, oop, r-s4

I would like to know about functionality of "@" (at sign) in R.
Let's say:
In the example below if I call `perf1@x.values` it starts to show all `x.values`. but I cann't access to second value of x.values by calling `perf@x.values[2]` !

```
> str(perf1)
Formal class 'performance' [package "ROCR"] with 6 slots
  ..@ x.name      : chr "False positive rate"
  ..@ y.name      : chr "True positive rate"
  ..@ alpha.name  : chr "Cutoff"
  ..@ x.values    :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:3966] 0 0.0005 0.001 0.0015 0.0015 0.002 0.0025 0.0025 0.003 0.0035 ...
  ..@ y.values    :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:3966] 0e+00 0e+00 0e+00 0e+00 5e-04 5e-04 5e-04 1e-03 1e-03 1e-03 ...
  ..@ alpha.values:List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:3966] Inf 0.996 0.993 0.986 0.98 ...
```

I wonder what is usage of "@" sign in R?
and how can I call certain values by using @ sign?
thanks

Comment: is this really need a regex tag?

Comment: `perf@x.values` is a `List of 1`, which *contains* that vector. You meant to do `perf@x.values[[1]][2]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[S4](http://rgm3.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM/R_rdfile?f=methods/man/Methods.Rd&d=R_rel) objects are lists with nodes or leaves (which are technically calls ['slots'](http://rgm3.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM/R_rdfile?f=methods/man/slot.Rd&d=R_rel)) that are accessible with the [`@`](http://rgm3.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM/R_rdfile?f=base/man/slotOp.Rd&d=R_rel) operator just as S3 objects are accessed with [`$`](http://rgm3.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM/R_rdfile?f=base/man/Extract.Rd&d=R_rel).

Take a look at:

```
str( perf1@x.name )
str( perf1@y.name )
```

Notice that these may contain ordinary S3 lists as with:

```
str( perf1 @ x.values) # a list
str( perf1 @ x.values[[1]] ) # a numeric vector
perf1 @ x.values[[1]][1]   # the first value in `x.values`
```

It's considered poor form to do this, since the authors of S4 objects are *supposed* to equip you with accessor functions that allow you to get anything that would be useful.

Comment: That wasn't my edit.  I only added links to documentation.  Since it took me a while to find the relevant pages (S4 documentation is rather scattered around), I thought that would be useful.

Comment: OK, looking at the revisions, apparently it was my edit.  I did drop a croissant on my keyboard while I was updating your question, so it's either that or my fat fingers that caused the typo.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the other edits. Does make answer more useful.